# Expect with ssh not working every time

Tags: bash, expect

I created script with `expect` + `ssh` + `bash executed command` to automate some process on remote machine.

Problem is that it is not working everytime.

- Sometimes it hangs on `password:`
- Sometimes it logins properly but do not `execute remote command`, just exit after timeout.

Here bash is script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="user"
PASSWORD="password"
MACHINES="host1 host2 host3 host4"

ex() {

expect -c "
                log_file ${MACHINE}.log;#
                set timeout 8;
                spawn ssh $USER@$MACHINE
                expect -re \".*ssword: \" {send \"$PASSWORD\n\"}
                expect -re \".*host-.* \" { send \"sudo su -\r\"}
                expect -re \".*user: \" { send \"$PASSWORD\r\"}
                expect -re \".*# \" { send \"/usr/local/bin/REMOTE.COMMAND.sh\r\"}
                expect -re \".*# \" { send \"exit\r\"}
                expect -re \".*host-.* \" { send \"exit\r\"}


"

}

machines() {

for MACHINE in $MACHINES ; do

ex &
sleep 0.5

done
}


machines
```

Here is my **working solution** - if there is something wrong/not efficient comment please:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="user"
PASSWORD="password"
MACHINES="host1 host2 host3 host4"

ex() {

expect -c "
        log_file ${MACHINE}.log;#
        match_max 100000;
        set timeout 30;
        spawn ssh $USER@$MACHINE
        expect {
                -re \".*ssword: \" {send \"$PASSWORD\r\"; exp_continue }
                -re \".*user@host-.*\" { send \"sudo su -\r\"; exp_continue }
                -re \".*ssword.*:.*\" {send \"$PASSWORD\r\"; exp_continue }
                -re \".*host-.*# \" { send \"/usr/local/bin/REMOTE.COMMAND.sh\r\"; }
        }
        expect {
                -re \".*host-.*# \" { send \"exit\r\"; }
        }
        expect {
                -re \".*user@host-.*\" { send \"exit\r\"; }
        }

"

}

machines() {

for MACHINE in $MACHINES ; do

ex &
sleep 0.5

done
}

machines
```

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps, you need to put `exp_continue` after `send \"$PASSWORD\n\";`...

Comment: Just there or after every line? And how about \n or \r at the end of command?

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problem once.

The problem was due to my SSH usage history, and my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` data.

You should try add options to your SSH command, so that it always behave the same wether you have already connected the host or not.

For example :

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

You might want to use different kind of authentication with option `PubkeyAuthentication`.

Comment: How about expect script? Is it set properly? Should I end lines with \r or \n? Maybe it should be done another way?

Comment: I can't tell, i was using it via python expect module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?:

```
expect -c "
    log_file ${MACHINE}.log;#
    set timeout 8;
    spawn ssh $USER@$MACHINE
    expect {
        -re \".*ssword: \" {send \"$PASSWORD\n\";exp_continue}
        -re \".*host-.* \" { send \"sudo su -\r\";exp_continue}
        -re \".*user: \" { send \"$PASSWORD\r\";exp_continue}
        -re \".*# \" { send \"/usr/local/bin/REMOTE.COMMAND.sh\r\";exp_continue}
        -re \".*# \" { send \"exit\r\"}
        -re \".*host-.* \" { send \"exit\r\"}
   }     
"
```

Besides, I have never used `expect` in a background process.

Comment: This one is not working for me, seems like there is no queue/order for that commands. Maybe there is also problem with matching PROMPT? How to set properly that kind: `user@host-city:~$ `? I'm having problem with `$` and `~` signs.

Comment: oh wait.... can you run it for a single MACHINE, in foreground? what point does the script stop? you can update the script based on that info.

Comment: I think I've fixed this problem. Seems I had problems with detecting `right prompt`, with `ending "\r" instead of "\n"` and `splitting -re into 3 expect { } lines` so it does not go into loop when trying to logoff from machine and going back to same prompt in same expect {}.

Comment: why don't you just `spawn ssh $USER@$MACHINE /usr/local/bin/REMOTE.COMMAND.sh` ? You could get rid of `send exit` & `send ...REMOTE.COMMAND...` part. Only thing expect would have to enter would be password.

Comment: Because of authentication and changing privilege. Sure it can be done using key auth and sudo allow for execution, but this is not the question in this case.